# -anus vs. -inus in (Classical) Latin

Tags: etymology, latin, affixes

Latin has some suffixes that turn nouns into adjectives. But there doesn't seem to be much rhyme or reason to which suffixes get applied to which nouns. For example:

- `felis`->`felinus`
- `canis`->`caninus`

But

- `apis`->`apianus`
- `avis`->`avianus`

Does anyone know where this distinction comes from? Was there perhaps an ending in Old Latin that influenced the choice of suffix and then disappeared?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a source for this at hand, but I would assume that the -anus suffix originated in a-stems: that is, the original suffix was -nus, but added to an a-stem it was -a-nus. This -anus would then have spread by analogy to nouns that aren't a-stems, too.

This is a common type of process; for a close parallel cf. the Greek feminine suffix -ssa, which originally arose by the addition of *-ya to t- and k-stems (e.g. *melit-ya > melissa "bee", *Phoinik-ya > Phoinissa "Phoenician woman"), but then became productive with all kinds of nouns (e.g. basilissa "queen").

Comment: Sure. The -a stem verbs were all regular, for instance, and any borrowed or derived verbs (repetitives in -to, for instance -- cano/canto) all were regular first-conjugation verbs. For derived nouns, the -a/-us thematic declensions were also the model. That's the norm; in English reified irregular nouns or verbs become regular (_Toronto Maple Leafs/*Leaves_)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific in this case? What would the old stems have been for apis and avis?

Comment: @AnschelSchaffer-Cohen I'm not sure if your comment is addressed to me or jlawler, but if the former: it's not that apis and avis once had different stems, but that the suffix originated in a different stem class and then spread out from there.

Comment: OK. But is there any good reason why it spread to some words and not others? There doesn't seem (to me) to be any phonological or semantic distinction at play.

Comment: @AnschelSchaffer-Cohen I don't know; I haven't look at the data. These kind of analogical extensions tend not to be too predictable.